# How can I have darker gridlines for theme_bw() in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can I get slightly darker gridlines for `theme_bw()` in ggplot2?

I have seen some some answers, but most are too complicated using `theme()`.

Is there a easier way?

```
corr.plot.contour(data=foo1,x='log(area)',y='log(fd)',xl='Basa(log)',yl='Flo'+stat_smooth(method="lm",formula=y~x)+theme_bw()+ggsave("xyz.png")
```

[image]

Comment: how is `theme(panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "black"))` too complicated?

Comment: Because it doesn't bring the white background like theme_bw() which is important for scientific publications? BTW, can you please show how to make it white background like theme_bw()

Comment: you can simply do  `... + theme_bw() + theme(panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "black"))`

Comment: That's what I wanted! :)

Comment: I usually type `theme_bw()` into the console and look at all the possible options. I usually find what I want that way.

Comment: What's on earth is `corr.plot.contour` ?

Comment: Oh, I just wrote a function for it with some defaults as I use it many times. And named it as such,. :-)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From [beetroot's comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24659780/how-can-i-have-darker-gridlines-for-theme-bw-in-ggplot2/24660108#comment38228757_24659780).

```
corr.plot.contour(data = foo1, x = 'log(area)', y = 'log(fd)', 
                              xl = 'Basa(log)', yl = 'Flo' + 
stat_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y~x) + 
theme_bw() + 
theme(panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "#808080")) + 
    ggsave("xyz.png")
```

Comment: I have already voted up! Also, this is the complete answer I was looking for.